# Is it understandable to say "I'm listening to the 70's"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Is it grammatically correct and understandable to say the following, where the word "music" is omitted.?

> I'm listening to the 70's"

Comment: Is this in the general context of a conversation about music?

Comment: One could argue that without some context, it's far too broad. Film music? Classical music? News reports?

Comment: "Seventy, seventy-one, seventy-two, seventy-three, seventy-four, seventy-five, seventy-six, ..."

Comment: *Context is everything. Resistance is futile*. There were 70's and 80's tapes of Mafia bosses. The 70's were the toughest to listen to.

Comment: It would be more useful to ask "What is the usual term for music from the 70s?" To which the answer would be something like "seventies music", rather than "seventies". You could look up [seventies](https://www.lexico.com/definition/seventy) in a dictionary too; Lexico gives "The numbers from seventy to seventy-nine, especially the years of a century or of a person's life" but doesn't mention music.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Just so we're clear, "grammatically correct" and "understandable" are two totally different questions.
2. As the comments hint, meaning is created by context. You have presented the sentence out of context. As it stands, no, the listener has no way to guess that you're talking about music. If you walked up to a stranger on the street, blurted this sentence, and walked away, your meaning would not be understood.
3. *Assuming* that this sentence were instead found in a context that established the topic of music, and in which people talked about listening to various genres or categories, sure; the meaning could be perfectly clear:

> "I'm listening to a lot of 90s music lately. Getting sentimental about Vanilla Ice."
> "Yeah? I'm listening to the 70s."

4. Is it "grammatically correct"? Sure, why wouldn't it be? "The 70s" can be a phrasal noun and serve as an object.
5. Also note, *style* is a separate topic from grammaticality. Some guides would tell you not to use an apostrophe to form a plural, thus "70s" rather than "70's." (And some might insist that you spell it out.)